# Disk corrupting over and over

Tags: hard-drive, disk-controller

I have re-installed windows, both the Vista Home Premium x86 that came on it and Win7 Pro x64. I am using Gateway GT5674 with an AMD Phenom quad core CPU. Everything is stock except the GeForce GT 9800 vid card.

The problem is the the file system keeps getting corrupted. It usually takes a few days, but it will start reporting disk errors and starts running chkdsk.

At one point I could not even reformat the C drive using Windows setup. I had a neighbor create a recovery CD that had BartPE on it. I deleted all partitions and the created and formatted the drive. The took a while, about 3 hours on a 500G drive.

But I was able to use the disk again. I reinstalled Windows 7 x64 and it was working perfectly until yesterday when it has all started again.

I suspect the HD controller, but am not sure how to check it. Any clues?

Comment: Is there anything in specific that you find is becoming a problem now?

Comment: It's probably best to start with a chkdsk /r c: and see what results you get from that to give us a better clue what's going on.  You can run that from the bartpe disk.  It's more likely to be the disk than the controller though, they have a much higher failure rate.

Comment: When I've seen this it's been the HD controller board in the PC.  Of course that's usually integrated into the motherboard now.  You should, of course, run a vigorous test of your RAM, because that could also be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run a full disk check on the drive, including physical/sector check? It sounds as though the hard drive may be failing. You can usually download a utility from the hard drive manufacturer to test the drive - Seagate, Western Digital etc along with `chkdsk` in Windows.

Comment: I figured when I reformatted using BartPE all was well. No errors were found m

Comment: It auto-ran chkdsk the last few times it rebooted. Last time if couldn't even read most of the sectors.Now it doesn't even recognize the drive in bios.

Comment: Exactly... The drive is failing/has failed. You should replace it. BTW chkdsk doesn't automatically do a surface (sector) scan. You have to do it manually.

Comment: It's happen again. I'm going to replace the HD, but I'm considering a SSD for boot drive.

Comment: Edit: s happen again. I'm going to replace the HD, but I'm considering a SSD for boot drive. But until then I'm going to try partitioning off the sectors that contain the problem. I'm assuming that low level addressing mirrors the physical layout of the disk's tracks.  And as far as I know the boot track are the first tracks. With that in mind I'm goon to delete all partitions and then create 1 50g partition. Then I'll allocate the rest of the drive to a second partition. I'll make the 2nd partition my primary and install win7 there.

Comment: You can try that but a failing drive is (generally) - a failing drive. Once you get a few failures it's likely the problem will only get worse. Drives are cheaper than time - save yourself the headaches and just go buy a new drive.